# Ventura would not read SanDisk SSD after update

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, ssd, kernel-panic, ventura

Help!
Mac info:

- Macbook Pro 15', 2017
- 2,9 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i7
- 16 GB RAM
- Ventura 13.4.1 (22F82)

What happened:

1. Working on Premiere Pro from a SanDisk Extreme Pro® Portable SSD USB-C 1TB
2. Connected an external HDD to copy files
3. Suddenly, Mac freezes and restarts (possible kernel panic)
4. Once up again, I decide to update the System Software (Ventura upgrade, no change between OS). Both drives were connected to the Macbook during this process.
5. After booting (did not disconnected any of the drives) Mac won't show any connected drive.
6. Unplugged the drives and reboot Mac.
7. Popup saying Disk is not readable:

[image: Disk is not readable]

8. I opened Disk Utility and the disk is actually there

[[image: I opened Disk Utility2]]

9. When performing a First Aid repair (multiple times), it says everything is OK

[image: When performing a First Aid repair]

10. Terminal shows the SSD this way.

[image: Terminal shows the SSD this way.]

...and when trying to perform a `repairVolume` it says the following:

[image: it says the following:]

```
[Mojave: ~ femarino$ diskutil mountDisk disk2s1
Volume (s) mounted successfully
[Mojave:~ femarino$ diskutil repairVolume disk2s1
Started file system repair on disk2s1
Checking file system and repairing if necessary and if possible
Volume is already unmounted
Performing fsck_msdos -y /dev/rdisk2s1
** /dev/rdisk2s1
Invalid BS_jmpBoot in boot block: 000000
File system check exit code is 8
Restoring the original state found as unmounted
Error: -69845: File system verify or repair failed
Underlying error: 8
```

PD: Tools like iBoysoft show me the files in the SSD so I guess this was a problem caused during the Ventura update (from #4 onwards) and not because of the kernel panic... and I still hope that there is some fix to repair the "header" of the SSD to make it accessible again.

Is there anything I can do to fix the SSD and make it readable again **without** wiping the data?

Thank you!

Comment: The problem was most likely the sudden disconnect at the crash, not the subsequent update. FAT disks are particularly at risk from this, because they are not journaled file systems. Your best bet will be the recovery software, to another drive. Unless you absolutely need cross platform compatibility, don't use FAT. Even then, it's better to invest in enabler software for your other platform than use FAT, for many reasons. FAT also cannot handle unix file permissions or Apple's 'container' structures.